# Get a list of unmountable drives using Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I would like to obtain a list of drives that are unmountable/ejectable using Cocoa/Objective-C under OS X.

I was hoping that NSWorkspace getFileSystemInfoForPath::::: would help me:

```
NSArray* listOfMedia = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] mountedLocalVolumePaths];
NSLog(@"%@", listOfMedia);

for (NSString* volumePath in listOfMedia)
{
    BOOL isRemovable = NO;
    BOOL isWritable  = NO;
    BOOL isUnmountable = NO;
    NSString* description = [NSString string];
    NSString* type = [NSString string];

    BOOL result = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] getFileSystemInfoForPath:volumePath 
                                                             isRemovable:&isRemovable 
                                                              isWritable:&isWritable 
                                                              isUnmountable:&isUnmountable 
                                                                description:&description
                                                                       type:&type];
    NSLog(@"Result:%i Volume: %@, Removable:%i, W:%i, Unmountable:%i, Desc:%@, type:%@", result, volumePath, isRemovable, isWritable, isUnmountable, description, type);
}
```

Output:

```
...
Result:1 Volume: /Volumes/LR Photos, Removable:0, W:1, Unmountable:0, Desc:hfs, type:hfs
...
```

"LR Photos" is an external drive (connected via Thunderbolt) that should be removable and/or unmountable (or, at least I think it should be). :)

Should I be going about this a different way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does Disk Utility say about the volume? What happens if you try to eject it in the Finder?

Comment: How is the "LR Photos" drive formatted?

Comment: Thank you for the great response. All I am really trying to do is build up a list of all the drives attached to the machine that *could* be ejected/unmounted if I wanted to do so.

Right now I do that via the Finder, but I'd like to do it from one place (a Menubar Extra, etc.). I know there are apps in the Mac App Store that do this, but I wanted to write my own. :)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `diskArbitration` [framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DiskArbitration/Reference/DADisk_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011609-CHDADiskhDataTypes-DontLinkElementID_2).

```
#import <DiskArbitration/DiskArbitration.h>
   +(NSMutableArray *)getListOfEjectableMedia
{
    NSArray *mountedRemovableMedia = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:nil options:NSVolumeEnumerationSkipHiddenVolumes];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSURL *volURL in mountedRemovableMedia)
    {
        int                 err = 0;
        DADiskRef           disk;
        DASessionRef        session;
        CFDictionaryRef     descDict;
        session = DASessionCreate(NULL);
        if (session == NULL) {
            err = EINVAL;
        }
        if (err == 0) {
            disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(NULL,session,(CFURLRef)volURL);
            if (session == NULL) {
                err = EINVAL;
            }
        }
        if (err == 0) {
            descDict = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
            if (descDict == NULL) {
                err = EINVAL;
            }
        }
        if (err == 0) {
            CFTypeRef mediaEjectableKey = CFDictionaryGetValue(descDict,kDADiskDescriptionMediaEjectableKey);
            CFTypeRef deviceProtocolName = CFDictionaryGetValue(descDict,kDADiskDescriptionDeviceProtocolKey);
            if (mediaEjectableKey != NULL)
            {
                BOOL op = CFEqual(mediaEjectableKey, CFSTR("0")) || CFEqual(deviceProtocolName, CFSTR("USB"));
                if (op) {
                    [result addObject:volURL];
                }
            }
        }
        if (descDict != NULL) {
            CFRelease(descDict);
        }
        if (disk != NULL) {
            CFRelease(disk);
        }
        if (session != NULL) {
            CFRelease(session);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Update:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)getListOfEjectableMedia {
    NSArray *mountedRemovableMedia = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:nil options:NSVolumeEnumerationSkipHiddenVolumes];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    DASessionRef session = DASessionCreate(NULL); // Create the DASessionRef object outside the loop.
    for (NSURL *volURL in mountedRemovableMedia) {
        DADiskRef disk = DADiskCreateFromVolumePath(NULL, session, (__bridge CFURLRef)volURL); // Use the same session object for each disk.
        if (disk != NULL) {
            CFDictionaryRef descDict = DADiskCopyDescription(disk);
            if (descDict != NULL) {
                CFTypeRef mediaEjectableKey = CFDictionaryGetValue(descDict,kDADiskDescriptionMediaEjectableKey);
                CFTypeRef deviceProtocolName = CFDictionaryGetValue(descDict,kDADiskDescriptionDeviceProtocolKey);
                if (mediaEjectableKey != NULL) {
                    BOOL op = CFEqual(mediaEjectableKey, CFSTR("0")) || CFEqual(deviceProtocolName, CFSTR("USB"));
                    if (op) {
                        [result addObject:volURL];
                    }
                }
                CFRelease(descDict);
            }
            CFRelease(disk);
        }
    }
    CFRelease(session); // Release the DASessionRef object after the loop.
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to create the session outside the `for` loop?

Comment: @Mojo66 Yes, it would be better to create the DASessionRef object outside the for loop and reuse it for each disk. This would avoid unnecessary overhead in creating a new DASessionRef object for each disk.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `getFileSystemInfoForPath:` is not really the right way to do this. What removable means is that the volume is on removable media such as a CD or DVD. In practice unmountable seems to give the same results as removable. See for example, this post on [results using getFileSystemInfoForPath](http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2005/May/msg02607.html). So unless you want to simply know if a volume is on removable media, you'll need to use another technique.

What you really want to check is the connection bus type of the volume. Firewire, USB, Thunderbolt, etc. are unmountable in the sense you mean. You can see this information in Disk Utility if you select the volume and push the "Info" button under "Connection Bus". Getting this information programmatically is much harder and as far as I can tell is only possible using the IOKit. Details are in Apple's documentation on [Accessing Hardware from Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Intro/AH_Intro.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. And your suggestion to check the connection bus is enough for what I'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use command line version of Disk Utility app that is "diskutil", run it with parameter "list" and pipe output and get it in your program ( don't need to use cocoa ).