# How to find if a mounted drive really exists on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cocoa, boost, filesystems

What I actually was trying to achieve is to find out when a drive which I had mounted from network is disconnected.
For which I started with a very simple approach, I used:

boost::filesystem::exists

on the mounted path of the drive ( which we can find in /Volumes/ ).
e.g. for a drive on computer: 
smb://XYZ/drive
after mounting, i can see it like:
/Volumes/drive
and the later was the drive on which I was using boost::filesystem::exists,

So I was hoping as soon as I will disconnect the network, the mounted volume inside /Volumes will be cleared immediately and everything will work simply.

BUT,
later I realize that on network disconnection OSX takes like forever to clear drive from /Volumes directory.

Is there an apple API which can tell whether the amounted volume, which appears in /Volumes is a valid one or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the reason OSX takes forever to clear them out is because the network might go down for a few minutes and then come back up again. Removing the file system entries under `/Volumes` might cause a bunch of breakage which isn't necessary if the drives are just going to come back online again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method on `NSFileManager` that lets you easily look at mounted volumes:

> `- (NSArray*) mountedVolumeURLsIncludingResourceValuesForKeys:option` - Returns an array of URLs that identify the mounted volumes available on the computer.

I don't know how this deals with stalled mounts though. You will also need to find out if these mounted volumes are network volumes or disk images.

If you want notifications when volumes come and go, you can use the [File System Events API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). It is a bit more low level but you can basically ask it to 'notify me when the structure under `/Volumes/*` changes.

Comment: Hi Stefan,

This does not work, still the same problem, this API just lists down all the mounted volumes, but that is not of much help, I need to know whether the mounted volume I know of is still valid...

Answer (score 1):

You want `NSWorkspace`'s [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWorkspaceDidRenameVolumeNotification):

- `NSWorkspaceDidRenameVolumeNotification`
- `NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification`
- `NSWorkspaceWillUnmountNotification`
- `NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification`

The last three notifications contain a `@"NSDevicePath"` key in the `userInfo` dictionary. While `WillUnmount` isn't sent if the device is forcibly removed, `DidUnmount` does. Using a combination of the two, you can get a proper warning for "nice unmounts" of network volumes to handle things in an ideal scenario but in all cases, I've never had any real problems relying on `DidUnmount` to tell me a volume disappeared. I use this in shipping code in an app that's been out since 2003.

Comment: Hi Joshua,

In my code I was trying to avoid any event driven approach. So instead of listening to these notifications, is there any other way or some status corresponding to the volumes which I can read and understand that the mount is no more valid .?

Comment: Hi Prime, You can use diskArbitration framework. Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633425/get-a-list-of-unmountable-drives-using-cocoa

Comment: @PRIME I'm curious as to why you want to avoid an event driven approach -- why do you think polling is better?

Comment: @damian I'm curious for the same reason. Although I agree with Sheen's DiskArbitration suggestion, it's still allowing the system to tell you when things come and go and it's infinitely better than polling to ask "yeah, but is it REALLY there?" What use is it, given we have NO CONTROL of disk availability anyway.

Comment: That is, a yanked storage device or a downed network volume is an inherently unsolvable problem for software developers. All we can do is guard our writes with error correction and trust the system to tell us if/what didn't make it.

Comment: @damian : I am avoiding the event driven approach because it is pretty much difficult to achieve with the current architecture of my application.
Currently I need to modify the architecture to accommodate the monitoring of shared files, that is why I need this feature, This is a small part of cross platform file monitoring module which already works on polling approach, So I wanted to have some status kind of info which I can easily attached to per-existing architecture

Comment: Ahh. Well, you could set it up so that the event handling is converted into a form that you can poll: namely, listen for the event and when it's received modify some shared object that the rest of the architecture can happily poll. May be a bit ugly, but there you go.